# mysql fulltext search "all but" query

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I need to query the table for "all but keyword". Using just "-" doesn't work, and in fact [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html) says:

> Note: The - operator acts only to
>   exclude rows that are otherwise
>   matched by other search terms. Thus, a
>   boolean-mode search that contains only
>   terms preceded by - returns an empty
>   result. It does not return “all rows
>   except those containing any of the
>   excluded terms.”

The only workaround I found was "a* b* .... y* z* -keyword", as this allows all other results to match. Is there any other (cleaner) way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
NOT MATCH(field) AGAINST(keyword)
```